# Store express-session datas in firebase db

Tags: session, firebase, store

I set up my autentification method through steam openid and now I'm looking to store the datas in a firebase db for every new user that sign in on. I configured firebase to write datas, but I'm looking to save them with express-session. I tryed some npm modules like connect-firebase, but they seems outdated..

Answer (score 0):

try connect-session-firebase this is the updated version